# positiveButton, negativeButton and neutralButton are disable in alertdialog android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I would like to know why all buttons are disable in alert dialog. It was working very well and suddenly all have been desable.

my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

int id = item.getItemId();

switch (id) {

    case R.id.generate_pdf_2:
        //

        /*new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Criando Recibo")
                .setMessage("Tem certeza que deseja criar o recibo?")
                .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(which).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        GeradorRecibo geradorRecibo = new GeradorRecibo(getActivity(), cliente);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Recibo gerado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Não", null)
                .show();*/
```

// I try this, but in both examples AlertDialog doesn't work.

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Criando Recibo");
        builder.setMessage("Deseja criar o recibo?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                GeradorRecibo geradorRecibo = new GeradorRecibo(getActivity(), cliente);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Recibo gerado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        final Button btn = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        btn.setEnabled(true);
        dialog.show();
        return true;
```

I'M SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder( getActivity() );
AlertDialog  dialog =  alert.create();
alert.setTitle( "My title" );
alert.setPositiveButton( "Ok",  new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton ) {  
            //Do something
      }
});
alert.setNegativeButton("KO", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton ) {  
            //Do something
      }
});
alert.show();
```

Hope it helps.